# Command prompt error

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

While using command prompt in windows 8.1, it gives me error of "the device is not ready."
I tried `cd D:` & `cd d:\` also.
 But it is not working. What is going wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: when you receive "the device is not ready."? when you want to open **CMD** or when you want to run a command?

Comment: I found the question very clear, and it's the same question I want answered. -1 to the close votes. You guys are meant to be experts of some kind, and you don't understand this guys problem ?

Answer (score 1):

`D:` is probably your CD drive. If there is no data CD in the drive, you will not be able to change into that directory. This is not particular to Windows 8.1; it's the nature of the beast. If there's nothing there, you can't go there. You will have to provide more detail in your question if this does not answer it.

Answer (score 1):

```
the device is not ready
```

Typically this means the drive you're trying to switch to or access doesn't have media in it.  You might get this if you try to access a CD/DVD-ROM that doesn't have a disc in it, or a card reader that doesn't have a card in it.

If you get this with a flash drive, your flash drive is broken and probably needs to be replaced.

If you are attempting to access an external hard drive or CD/DVD-ROM, it may have a different letter than D:.  If you are following instructions that are telling you to run D:\setup.exe or similar, you may have to change the drive letter to E:, F:, etc.

If you get this with an SD card or similar, and you are sure you have the correct drive letter, the card may be broken and probably needs to be replaced.  When SD cards go out, they may not be recognized by any card reader anymore.